# Returning object created using new

Tags: c++, pointers, object, reference

I have the following methods:

```
void* func1()
{
    MyClass myClassObject;
    func2(myClassObject);

    //myClassObjects's changes from func2() should be available here

    //Todo - I want to make myClassObj's entire structure/data visible in another method myMain() - see below
}

void* func2(MyClass &myObj)
{
     //make changes to myObj
     //the return type does not make a problem here
     //so - (void*)(0) would/would not be fine. 
}

void myMain()
{
    doSomeX();

    MyClass x = func1();

    doSomeY(x);
}
```

The problem is myClassObject would go out of scope as func1() exits, and would return junk data to myMain().

So I created a reference to myClassObject inside func1() and returned that 
reference, only to know that the same out of scope issues arise here.

I tried using new to create another object of MyClass and returned that to myMain(). But, the problem is, the program crashes once I access the returned object inside myMain()

Also, if I declare the x in myMain as void* and do **x = func1()**, the program compiles, but the problem is when I typecast x to that of MyClass.

Problem statement: **Create an object in func1(), pass it to func2(), make changes to the passed object there, and return the same to myMain() and use the returned object there.**

**I am not supposed to alter the function prototype of func1().**

Comment: Avoid the `void*`. This is C++ not C.

Comment: I would agree the convention aspect, but the question is how do you accommodate my requirement within the specified constraints?

Comment: downvote for a ill posed question caused by a non-oo design, whose solution, if exists, is against all good oo practice of any kind.

Comment: Well the first thing I would do is smack the person who gave you the asinine requirement of using `void*`. It has it's uses but not there.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply return a copy of the object?

```
MyClass func1()
{
    MyClass myClassObject;
    func2(myClassObject);

    // do whatever you want with myClassObject

    return myClassObject;
}

void func2(MyClass &myObj)
{
     // make changes to myObj
     // Notice I am returning void, not void*
}

void myMain()
{
    doSomeX();
    MyClass x = func1();
    doSomeY(x);
}
```

---

If you do not want to alter the definition of `func1()`, then you should create a pointer in `func1()` using `new` and return that:

```
void* func1()
{
    MyClass *myClassPtr = new MyClass;
    func2(myClassPtr);

    // do whatever you want with myClassObject

    return myClassPtr;
}

// Notice I passed a pointer now, not a reference
void func2(MyClass *myObj)
{
     // make changes to myObj
     // Notice I am returning void, not void*
}

void myMain()
{
    doSomeX();
    MyClass* x = (MyClass*) func1();
    doSomeY(x);

    // Don't forget to delete
    delete x;
}
```

You will be dealing with pointers in this case.

Comment: I am not supposed to alter the function prototype of func1().

Comment: I agree with func2() though.

Comment: `func2()` can and probably should take it's argument by reference.

Comment: There's no indication the argument is optional.